# Question about a solution of a partial differential equation by separation of variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations

I'm trying to understand this text:
http://www.ekayasolutions.com/UCDMath/HeatCondSphere.pdf

But I'm having problem with this part:

> Whe have to solve:
>   \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial \tau}=\dfrac{1}{\xi}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2} \left(\xi\theta\right);\ 0<\xi<1,\ 0<\tau.
> \end{equation}
>   with the conditions:
>   \begin{align}
> \text{IC:}\hspace{2pc}&\theta(\xi,0)=1,&&\\
> \text{BC1:}\hspace{2pc}&\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial \xi}+Bi\theta=0,\text{ for } \xi=1,&&\\
> \text{BC2:}\hspace{2pc}&\left|\theta(0,\tau)\right|<\infty,&&
> \end{align}
>   and $Bi$ is a constant.

Then it uses the separation of variables, so $\theta(\xi,\tau)=\Phi(\xi)G(\tau)$ and the problem becomes
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=\dfrac{1}{\xi\Phi}\dfrac{d^2}{d \xi^2}\left(\xi\Phi\right).
\end{equation}

Then, by Newton's cooling law
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=-\lambda^2,\text{ with } \lambda>0,
\end{equation}
so the solution for $G(\tau)$ is
\begin{equation}
G(\tau)=c e^{-\lambda^2\tau}.
\end{equation}
Anb solving for $\Phi(\xi)$ gives
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\xi)=\dfrac{1}{\xi}\sin(\lambda\xi).
\end{equation}

Where $\lambda$ is a root or the equation:
\begin{equation}
1-\lambda\cot(\lambda)-Bi=0.\hspace{2pc}(♦)
\end{equation}

Then it states that the solution is
\begin{equation}
\theta(\xi,\tau)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty G(c_n,\tau)\Phi(\lambda_n,\xi)
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_n$ are all the roots of (♦), and **my question is** why does it sum all the roots and do not just one?

Comment: This is more of a math question than a physics one. But the answer is linearity. Not all solutions to differential equations can be written in factored form (your function $\theta$). However, given a linear differential equation, all solutions can be gotten as *linear combinations* of the factored solutions.

Comment: Then how do I know that function satisfy linearity?

Comment: The *function* doesn't satisfy linearity; rather, the *differential operator* does. Look [here for information about linear differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation).

Comment: @march: why not post that as an answer? OK it's a maths question, but it's physically motivated and I think an OK question for this site.